# How to calculate John Templeton's market zones?

Tags: investing, markets

Does anyone know how John Templeton calculated his market zones, as seen on page 42 here: https://books.google.com/books?id=GBdGV9hxRPcC&pg=PA42&lpg=PA42&dq=john+templeton+stock+market+zones&source=bl&ots=zlOXdTiQif&sig=i6y0AYVZi6rBHG_ilyYQB1b7RA0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjh-rXc3-rYAhVIRqwKHdfrDe8Q6AEIPzAC#v=onepage&q=john%20templeton%20stock%20market%20zones&f=false.

Or have a reference to how it is done?

Comment: Maybe it was a proprietary formula?  Or later on in the book?

Comment: This Q is asking for formulas, not opinions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a direct answer, but you might find it helpful:

> The economic theory developed by Templeton, Dobbrow & Vance, Inc. for calculating the normal level of stock prices is simple. There are only three elements:
>
> 1. Stock prices would be normal if they bore the same relationship to current earnings as has been customary for the latest 20 years.
> 2. Stock prices would be normal if they bore the same relationship to the current cost of replacing the assets of the corporations as has been customary in the latest 20 years.
> 3. When, because of changes in tax laws or changes in the money supply, high-grade preferred stocks sell lower in relation to dividends than has been customary in the latest 20 years, then it should be normal for common stocks to sell lower in relation to earnings; and vice versa.
>
> Although the theory is simple, the actual calculation involves many thousands of figures. We take care to define accurately each word used in the principles above; and then the arithmetic is worked out on the basis of a large sample of representative stocks.

source: http://sirjohntempleton.org/2010/08/10/the-templeton-letters-what-is-normal-for-stock-prices/

Comment: Do you know what is meant by "relationship" in #1? Using SP500, it is just another way of saying EPS is too high or too low? That's not a good gauge of timing though.

Comment: @4thSpace I think it refers to the average P/E ratio or a similar indicator